# Getting no data from SQL in PHP for android parsing

Tags: php, android, sql

I want so select SQL in PHP to parse the given data in Android Studio. The problem is that my php page return nothing. No error and no result. I'm absolutely stumped for a solution. Can you take a look at my PHP SQL select? Thanks!

```
$response = array();

$statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT username, vorname, name, gebdat, strasse, hausnr, ort, plz, einsatzort, einsatzland, berechtigung FROM user JOIN contacts on user_u_id = u_id JOIN account on a_id = account_a_id JOIN berechtigungen on b_id = berechtigungen_b_id JOIN ort on o_id = ort_o_id JOIN einsatzgebiet on e_id = einsatzgebiet_e_id");

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $username, $vorname, $name, $gebdat, $strasse, $hausnr, $ort, $plz, $einsatzort, $einsatzland, $berechtigung);

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["vorname"] = $vorname;
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["gebdat"] = $gebdat;
        $response["strasse"] = $strasse;
        $response["hausnr"] = $hausnr;
        $response["ort"] = $ort;
        $response["plz"] = $plz;
        $response["einsatzort"] = $einsatzort;
        $response["einsatzland"] = $einsatzland;
        $response["berechtigung"] = $berechtigung;
    }

echo json_encode($response);
```

The database connection is working fine. I've checked it with a simple select.

The SQL select works fine direclty in the database:

[image]

Comment: Can you `var_dump($statement)` before the while loop. I think the while loop is not running at all.

Comment: ... dude forgot the semicolon at the end of the var dump

Comment: object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(2) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }

Comment: @McStuffins Haha yes I've noticed it

Comment: Now var_dump the code inside the while before the while. Comment out the while

Comment: @McStuffins Don't know what you mean :|

Comment: Sorry. I am very sleepy. So, comment out all of the 'while' loop. Add this like above the comments var_dump(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement));

Comment: this is the result: `bool(true) {"success":false}`

Comment: Give me a minute to turn my pc on to rewrite your code

Comment: I can give you my db sturcture if you want

Comment: No need. I'm going to use your commands

Comment: In this example, I used PDO because I know PDO more than I know mysqli

Comment: @McStuffins I've posted the select result as a picture directly from my SQL

Comment: Let me know if my answer is way off.. I do not think that it is, but just let me know.

Comment: As an aside, your naming policy is rather poor. Read about table aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code. Below is some code and then an explanation of the code as well.

```
<?php

$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$responses = array();

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT username, vorname, name, gebdat, strasse, hausnr, ort, plz, einsatzort, einsatzland, berechtigung FROM user JOIN contacts on user_u_id = u_id JOIN account on a_id = account_a_id JOIN berechtigungen on b_id = berechtigungen_b_id JOIN ort on o_id = ort_o_id JOIN einsatzgebiet on e_id = einsatzgebiet_e_id");
$stmt->execute();

$content = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if(count($content) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($content as $stuff) {
        $response[$i]["success"] = true;
        $response[$i]["username"] = $username;
        $response[$i]["vorname"] = $vorname;
        $response[$i]["name"] = $name;
        $response[$i]["gebdat"] = $gebdat;
        $response[$i]["strasse"] = $strasse;
        $response[$i]["hausnr"] = $hausnr;
        $response[$i]["ort"] = $ort;
        $response[$i]["plz"] = $plz;
        $response[$i]["einsatzort"] = $einsatzort;
        $response[$i]["einsatzland"] = $einsatzland;
        $response[$i]["berechtigung"] = $berechtigung;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Lets walk through it piece by piece:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

What does it do?

This part of the code is what runs to create the connection with the database with the PDO driver.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT username, vorname, name, gebdat, strasse, hausnr, ort, plz, einsatzort, einsatzland, berechtigung FROM user JOIN contacts on user_u_id = u_id JOIN account on a_id = account_a_id JOIN berechtigungen on b_id = berechtigungen_b_id JOIN ort on o_id = ort_o_id JOIN einsatzgebiet on e_id = einsatzgebiet_e_id");
$stmt->execute();
```

What does it do?

This part of the code is what actually prepares and executes a given command.

```
$content = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

What does it do?

This part of the code is what actually returns content to your code. Here is an example of what a result would look like.

```
array(array(new stdClass()),array(new stdClass()),array(new stdClass()),array(new stdClass()))  ** and so on for however many results **


if(count($content) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($content as $stuff) {
        $response[$i]["success"] = true;
        $response[$i]["username"] = $username;
        $response[$i]["vorname"] = $vorname;
        $response[$i]["name"] = $name;
        $response[$i]["gebdat"] = $gebdat;
        $response[$i]["strasse"] = $strasse;
        $response[$i]["hausnr"] = $hausnr;
        $response[$i]["ort"] = $ort;
        $response[$i]["plz"] = $plz;
        $response[$i]["einsatzort"] = $einsatzort;
        $response[$i]["einsatzland"] = $einsatzland;
        $response[$i]["berechtigung"] = $berechtigung;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

What does it do?

This part of the code is where content will actually be returned from command. I am not sure exactly what you had going on here when I was reading it, but it looks a little funky. If I were you personally, I would of not used variables inside of the command to return because then there would be no point in the command. You have the variables already expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've found the problem! Theres something wrong with the multiple joins. When I just join on table it works but joining another dont.

Comment: I'll give you a thumbs up because it helped my :)